# React: Trying to require in image src from object properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, jsx

I'm trying to create a card game, so I downloaded 52 jpegs of cards and have them in a folder called JPEG in my src folder.
I made an array of cards that looks like this:

```
const cards = [{
name: 'aceHearts',
value: 1,
img: './JPEG/AH.jpg'
}, {
name: 'aceDiamonds',
value: 1, 
img: './JPEG/AD.jpg'
}
```

etc.

I'm trying to make it so that when a button is clicked, an image will change to whatever card is on top of the shuffled array, so like

```
<img src={cards[0].img} />
```

I tried importing the images in and that works, but it seems silly to me to have 52 imports at the top of my code. So I tried writing:

```
<img src={require('./JPEG/AH.jpg') />
```

and that works, the card is shown. But when I write

```
<img src={require(cards[0].img)} />
```

it tells me "Error: Cannot find module './JPEG/AH.jpg'" Which I don't understand, because it found it fine when I typed it out manually, but it can't find it when it's pulling it from the array? Is there any way to make this work, or should I be using an entirely different approach?

If it's relevant, the cards array is in a file called Cards.js which is in the src folder, and the JSX is in a file called App.js which is also in the src folder. I've imported cards into App and it seems to be able to access it fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add "" empty string on top something like:

```
<img src={require(""+cards[0].img)} />
```

Comment: Thank you, that works! It also works to write it as {require( ` ${cards[0].img }` )}